# how does this for loop translate to english?

Tags: java, for-loop, linked-list

So basically I got this code from my professor but I've never seen anyone write a for loop like this. I dont even know how to start reading it? Can someone tell me how you would read this in English first and then what's the best way to use this in a for loop? 
also dont think this info was is needed but just incase, we're working on linkedlists in java.

Thanks in advance

```
    public void delete(Object el) {    // find and remove el;  
    if (head != null)              // if non-empty list;
         if (el.equals(head.info)) // if head needs to be removed;
              head = head.next;
         else {
              SLLNode pred = head, tmp = head.next;
              for ( ; tmp != null && !(tmp.info.equals(el));
                      pred = pred.next, tmp = tmp.next);
              if (tmp != null)     // if found
                    pred.next = tmp.next;
         }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(x;y;z) { ...; }
```

is equivalent to

```
x;
while(y) {
  ...;
  z;
}
```

So

```
  for ( ; tmp != null && !(tmp.info.equals(el));
          pred = pred.next, tmp = tmp.next);
```

is equivalent to:

```
while(tmp != null && !(tmp.info.equals(el))) {
  pred = pred.next, tmp = tmp.next;
}
```

In English, it would be something like

> Until we find the element we're looking for, or the end of the list: update the predecessor and current element to their respective next elements

Answer (score 1):

The [Java for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) has the form:

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s);
}
```

Your sample code is:

```
for ( ; tmp != null && !(tmp.info.equals(el));
        pred = pred.next, tmp = tmp.next);
```

If we break it down, you can see there:

- is no *initialization* step
- two parts to the *termination*
- two (comma separated) statements in the *increment* step

In rough English:

- keep looping until `tmp` is `null` or `tmp` matches the element to be deleted, ie. iterate through the list until we reach the end or find a match
- each time through the loop, *increment* `pred` and `tmp` by pointing them to the next item

Comment: oh i was really confused on how it skipped initialisation. didn't know that was even possible, hence why i was having trouble following the code! Thanks a lot for the explanation! I definitely have a lot to learn haha!

Comment: No problem. _Theoretically_ any of the three `for` loop header expressions can be empty. However it would be unusual for the termination or increment expressions to be omitted as you typically need these. I have seen the following used for an infinite loop though: `for (;;) { ... }`

Comment: what would even be the point of an infinite loop? when would you want to use such a thing in real life?

Comment: Infinite loops do have their uses, eg. an event handler for a GUI. Such a program basically runs forever (until you exit) and you check for user input every so often in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop is made up of four parts: the *initialization expression*, the *termination expression*, the *increment expression*, and the *body*.

(There's also a *for-each* style loop which has different syntax, but that's not what we're talking about here.)

So to parse this apart:

- The *initialization expression* is empty (nothing before the first `;`)
- The *termination expression* is `tmp != null && !(tmp.info.equals(el)`
- The *increment expression* is `pred = pred.next, tmp = tmp.next`
- The *body* is also empty (after the closing `)` of the `for` expression, the next statement is just `;`

In plain English:

> As long as `tmp` is not `null`, but `tmp.info` is not our desired element `el`, continue moving `pred` and `tmp` to point to the successor elements in the linked list.

The termination condition of this loop is that either `tmp` is `null` (if `el` was not an element of the list at all), or `pred` points to the node *before* the node that had `el` as a value, and `tmp` points to the node that has `el` as a value.

Note that this code is written in a very terse style. This kind of style was common for low-level code 20+ years ago; nowadays when I see code like this it makes me think it was written by an old-timer.

I would probably write the same method like this instead:

```java
public void delete(Object item) {
    if (head == null) {
        // The list is empty; we have no work to do.
        return;
    }
    if (head.info.equals(item)) {
        // We're deleting the head of the list; just update our head reference.
        head = head.next;
        return;
    }
    SLLNode previous = head;
    SLLNode current = head.next;
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.info.equals(item)) {
            // Update the list to skip the current node, then we're done.
            previous.next = current.next;
            return;
        }
        // Move to the next node in the list.
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }
    // If we reached this point, the item was not found in this list.
    // There's nothing to do, so we're done anyway.
}
```